# Array element less than sign is not printing

Tags: php, arrays, element

I've got a PHP problem. When I have the following array:

```
$string = array('<','s');

echo $string[0];
echo $string[1];
```

Nothing is showing

It prints fine if I put any other special character or integer value in place of the 's'

```
$string = array('<','1');

echo $string[0];
echo $string[1];
```

output: <1

OR

```
$string = array('<','1#');

echo $string[0];
echo $string[1];
```

output: <#

Comment: `$string = array('<','s'); var_dump($string);` This show that the elements are there as expected.

Comment: It gets printed, you just don't see it! (Put your glasses on!) No, just right click -> view source code

Comment: `echo htmlentities($string[1]);`

Comment: If you output your PHP as plaintext you don't have to worry about HTML escaping. You can do this with `header('Content-Type:text/plain')` before echoing any output.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that your output is not being shown to you as expected because you are looking at it in a web browser.  Anything starting with a < character followed by a letter is going to be interpreted as an HTML tag.

If you look at the page source of your output, you will probably see what you are looking for.

I'm sure PHP has a way to output escaped HTML tags and such out to a page, but I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

when you echo '<', the browser assumes you opened a tag name & expects '>'. as you know, content inside < & > is a tag & doesn't show on output(tags are used for formatting & sometimes styling the page). so, use `echo htmlspecialchars($string[0])` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = array('<','s');
echo htmlentities($string[0]);
echo htmlentities($string[1]);
```

Comment: In this case, i need less than sign e.g < , i don't need htmlentities e.g &lt;

Answer (score 0):

**Less than** and **more than**-characters are typically used for defining elements in your html, therefore you must define that these characters should be output like *"normal characters"* instead:

```
&lt; = less than (<) 
&gt; = more than (>)
```

In your example:

```
$string = array(&lt;,'1');
```

Take a look at http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm and look in the "html name column"

You could aslo have a look at http://php.net/htmlentities